# unable to start zookeeper cluster

Tags: bigdata, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to configure a Zookeeper cLuster with three node on 3 different machine 
this is the zoo.cfg file I'm using on the three nodes

```
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10
# The number of ticks that can pass between
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
# do not use /tmp for storage, /tmp here is just
# example sakes.
#dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# the maximum number of client connections.
# increase this if you need to handle more clients
#maxClientCnxns=60
#
# Be sure to read the maintenance section of the
dataDir=/home/user/HA/zookeeper_data
dataLogDir=/home/user/HA/zookeeper_log

Server.1=Server1:2888:3888
Server.2=Server2:2888:3888
Server.3=Server3:2888:3888
```

when I start zk Server on three nodes with

```
zkServer.sh start
```

the three server work all in standalone mode 
[image]

what is wrong with this configuration ? and is there another way to start the cluster ?
thnak you

Answer (score 2):

After one hour of search I figured out that the problem was in the config file "zoo.cfg" 
exactly in the list of nodes and ips :

> Wrong configuration

```
Server.1=Server1:2888:3888
Server.2=Server2:2888:3888
Server.3=Server3:2888:3888
```

> Correct configuration

```
server.1=Server1:2888:3888
server.2=Server2:2888:3888
server.3=Server3:2888:3888
```

the issue is that the first S in "Server..." was in uppercase .
somtimes the solution is in the details ! 
thank you